# Stop ModalPopup Extender to popup

Tags: c#, javascript, .net, ajax, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I have a modal popup extender which fires on a button click ... now irrespective on the onclientclick function return value true/false its always poping up. I need to stop the modal to fire on return of false and modal to fire the return to true..how to do this?

Please find the code below :

```
<div style="text-align:center;" runat="server" id="pnlButton">          
    <asp:Button  CssClass="button" ID="btnBack" runat="server" Text="Back" 
        Width="120px" onclick="btnBack_Click" UseSubmitBehavior="false" />
    &nbsp;
    <asp:Button  CssClass="button" ID="btnCancel" runat="server" 
            Text="Cancel Request" Width="130px" onclick="btnCancel_Click" onClientClick="Validate();" />
</div>
<div style="text-align:center;">
<asp:Button  CssClass="button" ID="btnDone" Visible="false" runat="server" 
        Text="Done" Width="110px" onclick="btnDone_Click"   />
</div>

<ajaxToolkit:ConfirmButtonExtender ID="cbe" runat="server"
TargetControlID="btnCancel"
DisplayModalPopupID="ModalPopupExtender1"
ConfirmText="Are you sure you want to click this?" />
<ajaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender ID="ModalPopupExtender1" runat="server" TargetControlID="btnCancel"
PopupControlID="PNL" OkControlID="ButtonOk" CancelControlID="ButtonCancel" BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground" />
<asp:Panel ID="PNL" runat="server" Style="display: none; width: 400px; background-color: White;
    border-width: 2px; border-color: Black; border-style: solid; padding: 20px;">
    <h2>Are you sure you want to cancel this request?</h2>
    <br />
    <br />
    <div style="text-align: right;">
        <asp:Button ID="ButtonOk" runat="server" Text="Yes" CssClass="button" />&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <asp:Button ID="ButtonCancel" runat="server" Text="No" CssClass="button" />
    </div>
</asp:Panel>
```

Comment: I don't see an onclientclick anywhere. Seems like a javascript confirm would be easier to implement too.

Comment: In what situation would you not want to validate it?

Comment: When the javascript validations are firing in the page.. i need not to fire the pop up .else i need to fire the popup

Comment: Do you want to use ASP.NET validation or `Validate` is your client method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can open Popup from javascript

```
function ValidateAndOpen(){
if(Validate()){
var modalDialog = $find("ModalPopupExtender1"); 
// get reference to modal popup using the AJAX api $find() function    
  if (modalDialog != null) {
    modalDialog.show();
  }    
 }
return false;
}
```

You must set ClientIDMode="Static" on ModalPopupExtender 
and set OnClientClick="return ValidateAndOpen();"

Answer (score 0):

change you code to the following

```
 onClientClick="return Validate();"
```

Comment: i have tried that its not working... still its fires on return true and false

Answer (score 0):

Put this script onto your form:

```
 function pageLoad(sender, args) {
      if (args.get_isPartialLoad() === false) {
           $find("<%= ModalPopupExtender1.ClientID %>").add_showing(function (sender, args) { args.set_cancel(Validate()); });
      }
 }
```

Comment: Compilation Error 
Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately.

Comment: Compiler Error Message: CS0120: An object reference is required for the nonstatic field, method, or property 'System.Web.UI.Control.ClientID.get'

Line 34:     function pageLoad(sender, args) {
Line 35:         if (args.get_isPartialLoad() === false) {
Line 36:             $find("<%= ModalPopupExtender.ClientID %>").add_showing(function (sender, args) { args.set_cancel(ValidateControl()); });
Line 37:         }
Line 38:     }

Comment: @PeteEngineer, I had fixed script